# I need a better word to replace "poriferous" , is there any other word?

Tags: word-request

This is a composition of one of my students.

> The kitchen in my house is always very greasy. Even the kitchen ventilator can't do much to solve this problem.
>
> I've been worried about my grandmother's health especially her lungs because she is in the kitchen cooking everyday. And there's also air pollution while the oil smoke emits directly out of the house.
>
> I'm thinking about the future design of the kitchens. Will it be better if we design a totally enclosed ventilation system, which includes **poriferous** ceramic tiles, ceiling materials, to drain and centralize the oil smoke though special pipes.
>
> If so, there won't be nuisance grease in kitchens anymore, and we will have a cleaner environment.

I need a better word to replace "poriferous" , is there any other word?

BTW, I'll appreciate any proofreading comments.

Comment: The word you're looking for is **porous**.

Comment: though special pipes or through special pipes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word you have is fine, but I would say

> porous

is more commonly used. It has exactly the same meaning.